# Turkish airlines: can't re-schedule flight with changed date/time

Tags: air-travel, bookings, cancellations, turkish-airlines

We're having problems with Turkish Airlines's flight re-schedule system, and we're a bit in panic.

We - a group of 6 people - booked and paid for a flight from Budapest to Ankara with a stop in Istanbul, supposedly starting at this Monday (July 15th) 9:05. The booking was done in two parts, 3 people each, the problem is there with both reservation. When we attempted to do the online check in about an hour ago (July 13rd ~20:00), we were astonished to see the message on the check-in page that we have to re-schedule our flights (as we got no prior notification about this).

[image]

So we started changing the flight and got to the point when we selected the new times, as follows:

[image]

but when we click on "continue" to the next step - supposedly a summary before payment - we get a technical error, and are advised to check our selection again:

[image: A technical error occurred during flight selection. Please check your selection and try again.]

Is there something wrong with our re-scheduled flights, or is this a problem on Turkish Airlines's side? What should we do if we're unable to re-schedule our flight due to this error before the flight starts? We're heading to an event so getting there in time is our top priority.

We tried to contact their Hungarian customer service, but with no luck so far (possibly due to the late time, though we called them at 20:00 and they claim to be available 'till 20:30).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After failing on the official website on 2 different computers, I tried the Turkish Airlines mobile app. The experience wasn't flawless, but finally it worked while the website still shows an error:
[image: website error screenshot]

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately this pretty common behavior for the Turkish Airlines website, especially since they "upgraded" it a year or two back.  You can try using a different browser or using incognito mode, but odds are you'll hit the same problem again.

In general if you're getting an error like this the only option will be to contact Turkish airlines directly, or if your tickets were purchased via a travel agent (including an online travel agency) then contact the travel agency to see if they can help.

If you are unable to contact the local Turkish Airlines office, you can try calling the one in a different country - either Turkey (which is available 24x7) or somewhere like the US (+1 800 8748875, also 24x7, and available for free via services like Skype)

Comment: Thanks. In the end we used their Android app to check-in, where we didn't encounter any problem. We didn't even have to re-seclude.

Comment: @Doc Worth adding the OP’s solution to your answer for future reference?