# Can I reschedule a Turkish Airline ticket without paying the "call center price"?

Tags: bookings, turkish-airlines

I needed to change a ticket and the website did not let me change it online, claiming a series of errors. I called Turkish Airline to *open* the ticket so that I could pick a date later.

Today I called them to reschedule and they suggested that I should pay a 700€ difference (same as the original ticket price) instead of the 100€ price difference I find on their own website. They claim that prices on the phone differ, but then **they don't let you change online.**

Is there any way to reschedule the flight without getting this inflated price? Turkish sold me a ticket that I can change by "paying only the difference", only to find out that the difference is predatory.

Comment: Did you call their tech support to ask about the errors?

Comment: Unfortunately the TK website sucks, as does their phone support.  Try using the app - occasionally it'll work where the website doesn't.

Comment: @DJClayworth see https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/142040/12910. This is a common occurrence. My flight was 3 days later, I had no time to "report a bug" unfortunately. The website claimed that no flights were available on the selected dates and then it failed with "Call us" when trying to confirm one that was available.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up visiting a physical Turkish Airlines ticketing office and I got a better price than what I was offered on the phone. This might have been pure chance though since every call I made over the week brought up wildly different prices and availability, up to a 1200€ difference per person.

The frustrating part was that some options offered by the website were not immediately visible to the operators (also in the office). Some just said "can't see it", some said "can't book it". At the office I had to tell them each exact flight I wanted (different route/stops) and after nearly an hour of "checking availability" I was able to pay and get out.